# Cómo saber si ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 está referenciada a una fórmula o función en Excel

Tags: excel, macros, excel-2013

Estoy tratando de modificar la información que una macro de Excel importa desde una consulta de base de datos SQL, tengo en la macro esta línea de código:

```
Range("E11").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=datoempleadoperiodo(RC1,R1C3,R2C3,R3C3,R9C,1)"
```

Necesito saber si datoempleadoperiodo es una función, una fórmula o algo diferente y la forma de acceder a este para ver qué campos está consultando.Traté de dar clic derecho sobre ésta e ir a referencia, tal como se podría hacer desde Visual, pero al parecer no es el caso, no lleva a ningún lado.

Recién comienzo a entender el funcionamiento de las macros, espero puedan orientarme.

Comment: Sin más contexto que esa línea de código, podemos aventurar que se trata de una función personalizada, ya que NO es una función estandar, y a la vista está que NO es una fórmula, ni la notación entre paréntesis hace referencia a un rango.

Comment: Una fórmula es, por norma general, todo aquello que empiece por un =. Esa formula puede tener funciones o no. Pero como dice el otro comentario, tiene toda la pinta de que datoempleadoperiodo es una UDF.